# colorbox FULL SIZE Images

Tags: image-processing, colorbox

I'm NOT a programmer, just like to play with php, pictures, movies & music.
Being creative. I'm making a site with OSCommerce 234BS? It's working well just the colorbox is'n what I want. I have pictures in high quality and would like the visitors could watch them FULL SIZE, like when you click right on a picture & open it in a new window, because then you have also a zoom function.
See pictures
Thanks a lot for supportenter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iLLJ.jpg)

Comment: What kind of information are you after?

Answer (score 0):

I would like my bxgallery is like you can see on ebay. Mouse ober and click for larger image. Then you see the images expanded over the whole screen.

Comment: Nobody that can help me making the colorbox 100% of the screen? My pics are 1900*1600